# Image Comparison in selenium using sikuli

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

We are using sikuli for image comparison in our automation, but i'm getting below error when i ran the test.

We are using sikuli because we are doing image comparison for small part of the web page.

**Error i'm getting:**
FindFailed: can not find P(D:\Automation\test-data\Student.jpg) S: 0.99 on the screen.
  Line 1574, in file Region.java

**code is:**

```
public static void FindPattern(String BaseImage)
{
          try{
        Pattern imagepattern = new Pattern(BaseImage);
        imagepattern.similar((float)0.99);
        Screen screen=new Screen();
        screen.find(imagepattern)
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the same image work if you test it from Sikuli IDE? If it does then there could be couple of things which are causing the failure.

1.Application and script sync issue. You might be looking for the image even before it is available on the page.
2.The screenshot may be having too much of background in it.